# vs2005 project not compiling from command line but compiles within visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a project that must be compiled using VC++ 2005. I've installed Visual Studio 2005 Express and the solution compiles successfully within the IDE

I'm trying to get the same process running by a CI server (teamcity) however when I try to compile from the command line I get:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'user32.lib'

My command to compile from the command line is:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe my_app.sln

How can i compile this from the command line?

I've tried using `vcbuild`

> vcbuild /rebuild my_project.vcproj "Debug|Win32"

which produces the same result

Comment: The VS start menu folder provides diverse batch files to start a console. In the batch files, a variety of environment variables are set which are probably necessary to run VS tools properly. May be, it's worth to have a look at it. (I must admit I haven't used VS tools without IDE for a long time.)

Comment: @Scheff I did run it under a 'Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt' window

Comment: `.lib` files are needed to link against exported symbols of DLLs. Are you aware of `/L` command line option of compiler? I would try to locate `user32.lib` (probably in a platform SDK or something similar), and check whether the corresponding path appears after one of the `/L` options in link command line. Another option: Have a look at command line options in VS IDE. (They can be found in the project properties.) Check if there is something else which is missing on your console build command line.  (And, be aware of x86 vs. x64...)